# Non-resolvable parent POM for From Docker

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, maven-2

Hi I'm trying to run the following dockerfile which should:

1. create a fat jar springboot
2. and run it

```
FROM openjdk:17-alpine as build
WORKDIR /workspace/app
COPY mvnw .
COPY .mvn .mvn
COPY pom.xml .
COPY src src
RUN ./mvnw install -DskipTests
RUN mkdir -p target/dependency && (cd target/dependency; jar -xf ../*.jar)

FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ARG DEPENDENCY=/workspace/app/target/dependency
COPY --from=build ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/lib /app/lib
COPY --from=build ${DEPENDENCY}/META-INF /app/META-INF
COPY --from=build ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/classes /app
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Dspring.profiles.active=${ENV}", "-Djasypt.encryptor.password=${MASTER_PASSWORD}", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

when I launch the docker build.

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  72.35MB
Step 1/16 : FROM openjdk:17-alpine as build
 ---> 264c9bdce361
Step 2/16 : WORKDIR /workspace/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e9b5dd3bdd5d
Step 3/16 : COPY mvnw .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> eb136deee21e
Step 4/16 : COPY .mvn .mvn
 ---> Using cache
 ---> bbda18e60e07
Step 5/16 : COPY pom.xml .
 ---> b7ae10a2559c
Step 6/16 : COPY src src
 ---> 8f73e87e80ca
Step 7/16 : RUN ./mvnw install -DskipTests
 ---> Running in 1b0bd104bad8
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.florence:blockforgery.backend:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.florence:blockforgery.masterpom:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 11, column 13
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.florence:blockforgery.backend:1.0-SNAPSHOT (/workspace/app/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for com.florence:blockforgery.backend:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.florence:blockforgery.masterpom:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 11, column 13 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
The command '/bin/sh -c ./mvnw install -DskipTests' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

This is the POM of my project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.florence</groupId>
    <artifactId>blockforgery.backend</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.florence</groupId>
        <artifactId>blockforgery.masterpom</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <start-class>com.florence.blockforgery.Application</start-class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.florence</groupId>
            <artifactId>blockforgery.common</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

While this is the parent POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.florence</groupId>
    <artifactId>blockforgery.masterpom</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <aws.version>1.12.163</aws.version>
        <maven.compiler.target>${maven.compiler.source}</maven.compiler.target>
        <junit.jupiter.version>5.7.0</junit.jupiter.version>
        <junit.platform.version>1.8.1</junit.platform.version>
        <java-ipfs-http-client.version>v1.3.3</java-ipfs-http-client.version>
        <log4j.version>2.17.2</log4j.version>
        <mockito.version>4.3.1</mockito.version>
        <spring.version>2.6.4</spring.version>
        <aws.java.sdk.version>2.17.152</aws.java.sdk.version>
        <apache.http>4.5.13</apache.http>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
                <version>${aws.java.sdk.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

   <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.web3j</groupId>
            <artifactId>web3j-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ipfs</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-ipfs-http-client</artifactId>
            <version>${java-ipfs-http-client.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>auth</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>dynamodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>dynamodb-enhanced</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqs</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>s3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.22</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ben-manes.caffeine</groupId>
            <artifactId>caffeine</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>4.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.lingala.zip4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>zip4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.web3j</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-suite-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.platform.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-suite</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.platform.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>1.18.22</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jitpack.io</id>
            <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>rhazdev</id>
            <url>https://mymavenrepo.com/repo/NIp3fBk55f5oF6VI1Wso/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>florence-nexus-blockforgery</id>
            <url>https://nexus.florence-consulting.it/nexus/repository/maven-blockforgery/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>florence-nexus-blockforgery-releases</id>
            <name>Internal Releases</name>
            <url>https://nexus.florence-consulting.it/nexus/repository/maven-blockforgery-release/</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>florence-nexus-blockforgery-snapshots</id>
            <name>Internal Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://nexus.florence-consulting.it/nexus/repository/maven-blockforgery-snapshot/</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

I state that by running the:

```
 mvn clean install -DskkipTests
```

command from the console on Ubuntu everything works correctly.

These are my configurations:

1. **Maven** Apache Maven 3.8.4 (9b656c72d54e5bacbed989b64718c159fe39b537)
2. **JAVA** openjdk 17.0.3 2022-04-19
3. **DOCKER** Docker version 20.10.17, build 100c701
4. **S.O.** Ubuntu 20.04

Thank you very much for helping

Comment: Where is the `Dockerfile`? Next to the main pom or the master pom? Where are the two pom files relative to each other. You only copy one pom into the image in your dockerfile, yet you expect it to be able to resolve the parent somehow (which it seems is not in any public repository).

Comment: *Dockerfile* is next to main pom.  master pom in installed in the corporate Nexus

Comment: And how do you expect Maven inside the docker image to know that it should contact your corporate nexus to grab the parent POM? That's probably configured in your local settings *on the host computer*, but not inside of docker!

Comment: You container is not allowed/configured to acccess the repository manager...

Comment: I thought the configurations set in the POM were enough. How can I go about adding my masterpom to the image?

Answer (score 0):

Your parent `blockforgery.masterpom` is not installed in your container, nor deployed in a repository manager (nexus, artifactory, ...)

Either you publish the parent pom somewhere, or you'll have to push to your container and build the parent also.

Comment: **blockforgery.masterpom** it is installed in the corporate Nexus.

Comment: maybe you'll have to set the parent.relativePath too? sorry i have no other idea.